# Ensure files passed to log.SetOutput are closed properly

Tags: logging, go

Consider this package that configures a logging adapter based on the environment, and allows changes to logging output at runtime.

```
package mylog

import (
    "log"
    "os"
    "io"
)

const StdOut = "STDOUT"

var logger *log.Logger

func init() {
    outputLocation := os.Getenv("MY_LOG_OUTPUT")
    if outputLocation == "" || outputLocation == StdOut {
        log.SetOutput(os.Stdout)
        return
    }

    f, _ := getFile(outputLocation)
    log.SetOutput(f)
}

func getFile(path string) (*os.File, error) {
    openFlags := os.O_WRONLY | os.O_APPEND | os.O_CREATE
    f, err := os.OpenFile(path, openFlags, 0666)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    return f, nil
}

func SetOutput(w io.Writer) {
    logger.SetOutput(w)
}

func Debug(v ...interface{}) {
    log.Println(v...)
}
```

There are two problems that I have with this:

1. There is not a way of being sure that `w` passed to `SetOutput` is a `Closer`.
2. Even if I could be sure (reflection?), when do I close it?

Edit:
It's difficult to give a simple example of use case that causes a problem.  For example, it I import this package into a simple program that runs and exits, I could expose a method to close log files and call that (with `defer` or without) before that program finishes execution.  The real problem is with a long-running process (like a webserver) that does not have a point that you would want to close the log unless the process dies.

So part of my question is, is it even necessary to close the file?

Comment: To check if an `io.Writer` is also an `io.Closer` you just use a type assertion. But yes, there is no way to ensure it's closed. if your output is buffered and requires Close to flush it before exit, you need to setup and handler to do that on your own.

Comment: With regard to "when do I close it?" you should take a look at the `defer` statement [link](https://blog.golang.org/defer-panic-and-recover). Defer places functionality onto a call stack that is executed after the surrounding function exits. Using defer you can ensure that your file will be closed eventually.

Comment: @StewartGrant The problem with defer in this case is that it will cause the file to close before it can be written to (because it will only be written to when `log.Debug` is called from an importing package).  It may be the case that if I have a daemon process that's going to keep the file open all the time for logging that it doesn't matter whether it gets closed.  I welcome any opinions on that as well.